# i need an ancestral EU visa to work in UK

Tags: visa

I am to work temporarily as a carer and require an ancestral visa for the UK. THey stipulate a grandparent or parent of any EU country.
Both my parents and grandparents (deceased) were born in NEtherlands. 
I lost my dutch passport as I didn't fall in the 10 year rule.!!!
Please assist

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have misunderstood.  The UK ancestry visa is for those who have a grandparent who was [born in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa).  There is no visa for those with "a grandparent or parent of any EU country."

From the page linked above:

> You can apply for a UK Ancestry visa if you:
>
> - are a Commonwealth citizen
> - are applying from outside the UK
> - are able to prove that one of your grandparents was born in the UK
> - are able and planning to work in the UK
> - meet the other eligibility requirements

The third point disqualifies you.